# jQuery - best way to toggle classes in span button

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have one or more couples of YES - NO buttons made with  tags... precisely:

```
<label id='label-btn-yes_"+button_counter+"' class='ui-button ui-button-icon-only ui-widget ui-state-default ui-btn-expand-yes_"+button_counter+" '><span id='span-btn-yes_"+button_counter+"' class='ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick' onClick='expandYes(this,"+row_id+")'></span><span id='span-txt-yes_"+button_counter+"' class='ui-button-text'>Button</span></label>
<label id='label-btn-no_"+button_counter+"' class='ui-button ui-button-icon-only ui-widget ui-state-default ui-btn-expand-no_"+button_counter+" '><span id='span-btn-no_"+button_counter+"' class='ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick' onClick='expandNo(this,"+row_id+")'></span><span id='span-txt-no_"+button_counter+"' class='ui-button-text'>Button</span></label>
```

I tried to code like this to toggle buttons:

```
$(selector).removeClass("ui-icon-plusthick").addClass("ui-icon-minusthick").addClass("button-pressed").next().addClass("button-pressed");
if ( $(selector).attr("id") != $(node).find('.ui-icon-minusthick').attr("id") )
$(node).find('.ui-icon-minusthick').removeClass("ui-icon-minusthick").addClass("ui-icon-plusthick").removeClass('button-pressed').next().removeClass('button-pressed');
```

where $(selector) is the current "button" I am pressing at the moment and $(node) is the button found in the pressed state to toggle back to unpressed state.

When the "button" that's pressed is DIFFERENT from the current button I am pressing then it's ok and it works great, but my issue is when I press the SAME "button" looks like it toggles to unpressed but it goes back to pressed state...

So is there an elegant way to toggle the SAME button and make it remain unpressed if it was previously in pressed state?

Thanks in advance to all!
ciao,
Luigi

UPDATE:

you can see a test sample at this link:

http://nunzioluigi.com/test/test.php

I tried too toggleClass() but when I am in the same button it does the same behavior as addClass+removeClass...

Comment: jQuery.toggleClass() http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/ not what you want?

Comment: hello Khoi, thanks for your answer.. I tried with toggleClass but as far as I tried it does same thing as using addClass + removeClass... you can see a test sample at http://nunzioluigi.com/test/test.php .... maybe I used wrong way?...

Answer (score 1):

I solved by myself...

had to reverse the order of code:

```
if ( $(selector).attr("id") != $(node).find('.ui-icon-minusthick').attr("id") )
   $(node).find('.ui-icon-minusthick').removeClass("ui-icon-minusthick").addClass("ui-icon-plusthick").removeClass('button-pressed').next().removeClass('button-pressed');
$(selector).removeClass("ui-icon-plusthick").addClass("ui-icon-minusthick").addClass("button-pressed").next().addClass("button-pressed");
```

So now it works.

Thanks to all and to Khôi.

Ciao,
Luigi